# Users can't connect remotely to MySQL

Tags: mysql, networking, connection, connectivity

**Problem**

Users from other IPs on the (Windows XP) LAN suddenly cannot connect to my local MySQL server.

**Background**

I've set up MySQL on my local Windows computer so that other computers on the network have access to the root account. I've added each IP as a host for root. Up to some weeks ago, things worked flawlessly and I could connect to the server programatically and using various MySQL admin tools. Now, however, the MySQL server simply refuses connections from those IPs and I can't figure out why.

The network changes that I've done are: changing network card for two (of three) computers and fiddled around with MySQL settings. None of which should have caused this problem. I've tried adding a new user with all relevant hosts, but I get the same type of error:

> MySQL Error number 1045 Access denied
>   for user 'root'@'shop' (using
>   passwords: YES)

The odd part is that the computer name, 'shop', is used instead of the IP. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that pops into mind is Windows Firewall, which could have got re-enabled if you swapped NICs on the host computer.

My next suggestion would be to use a sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) on the host computer and see what exactly happens packet-wise. You can use filters to make to reduce the output - they're very simple and easy to use. This tool has saved me countless hours of debugging.

-EDIT-

Another possible cause might be that your server somehow decided to resolve IPs to hostnames, in which case ip addresses may no longer work - one would need to add hostnames to the allowed list. Not sure if it works this way for MySQL though.

Comment: Windows firewall isn't enabled. I'm using another software firewall but that's completely disabled.

Thanks for suggesting Wireshark. I feel I need to add that the clients are able to connect to the server but that access is denied for them.

Comment: You we're sorta right! I've already added each computer's name as host but written them in uppercase instead of proper capitalization - thought mysql treated host names case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, IPs seem to be resolved now and hostnames are used. Did you grant access to root@shop? Did you flush privileges?

Comment: yes, I've added both names and IPs for each computer. But I haven't flushed priviligies. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: That was more than a tip. That was the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you have turned off TCP connections in MySQL?

Also, is the MySQL port open in your firewall?

Comment: Turned off TCP connections? I don't recall touching settings related to that. The post is open but I've even disabled the firewall on the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your IP (DHCP?), make sure to correct it in my.cnf if you bound mysqld to your lan ip:

```
[mysqld]
...
bind-address=192.168.x.y
```